# No tag for sensitivity?

Tags: discussion

I tried to add a tag for "sensitivity" and was not able to do so; I did add one for specificity. It's very surprising these aren't already tags, and I am not sure what's up

Comment: I would have suspected that it was already a synonym for something else, but I just checked & I didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a typing problem.  Because there exists [sensitivity-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensitivity-analysis), after you typed "sensitivity", the system would assume you meant that tag.  *As soon as you type another character,* it knows you mean something else.  Type a space at that point and you'll be fine.

Comment: There now exists a [tag:sensitivity] tag, which I created when testing out this answer.  It is not yet attached to any questions because I don't know which question(s) you had in mind.

Comment: Ah ha. Now I see. Thanks